# Redefining \smallsetminus by smaller \setminus

Tags: math-mode

I don't like the appearance of `\setminus` (it's big and doesn't look good), and also don't like the appearence of `\smallsetminus` (its size is perfect but, in my opinion, it's too horizontal and it's not vertically center).

I found that in normal math this is what I can use:

```
\[
    A \mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\setminus$}}} B
\]
```

Which looks like [image: A \xsetminus B]. But it's super thin. So I made the next one (I don't really now how many of those commands work, it has a lot of trial and error):

```
\[
    A \mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathrlap{\setminus}{\hspace{.2pt}\setminus$}}} B
\]
```

Which looks more like [image: A \xbsmallsetminus B].

At this point I got the desired thickness. But it's ugly if you zoom it, it's not *well designed*, and does not match the correct size if it's in a subscript (and less in a sub subscript).

### Question:

Any ideas about how to redefine `\setminus` in order to get that orientation (the same as the usual `\setminus`), more or less the height is shown in the pictures and the same thickness of the usual `\setminus` (in all sizes: displaysytle, textstyle (the same as displaystyle), scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle)?

I listen to all your ideas (including that ones where you try to convince me that the usual `\setminus` or `\smallsetminus` ar perfect).

**EDIT:** Here your are an example of how all looks (`\setminus`, my macro, `\smallsetminus`):

[image: Comparison1]

Here another example including @AndrewSwann `\fgebackslash` (`\setminus`, `\smallsetminus`, my macro, modified smaller `\fgebackslash`, `\fgebackslash`)

[image: Comparison2]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that you don't like the existing shapes in the available fonts, my other suggestion would be to use `tikz` to draw the symbol; you can then adjust all parameters and coordinates as you wish.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,tikz}

\newcommand{\mysetminusD}{\hbox{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.6pt,line cap=round] (3pt,0) -- (0,6pt);}}}
\newcommand{\mysetminusT}{\mysetminusD}
\newcommand{\mysetminusS}{\hbox{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.45pt,line cap=round] (2pt,0) -- (0,4pt);}}}
\newcommand{\mysetminusSS}{\hbox{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.4pt,line cap=round] (1.5pt,0) -- (0,3pt);}}}

\newcommand{\mysetminus}{\mathbin{\mathchoice{\mysetminusD}{\mysetminusT}{\mysetminusS}{\mysetminusSS}}}

\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}

\verb+\setminus,\mysetminus,\smallsetminus+:
\begin{displaymath}
 A\setminus B \qquad A \mysetminus B \qquad
A\smallsetminus B 
\end{displaymath}

\verb+\mysetminus+ in display, script and scriptscript styles
\begin{displaymath}
 A\mysetminus B\quad \scriptstyle A\mysetminus B \quad
\scriptscriptstyle A\mysetminus B
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

The code provides separate commands for displaystyle, textstyle, scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle and uses `\mathchoice` to select the correct one.  I have put the textstyle version equal to the displaystyle one.  In the `\tikz` command you can now specify exactly which line to use and what width it should have.  I have made the ends of the lines round, instead of square, with the `line cap` option.  Finally, if neccessary you can specify a different bounding box for these characters by addingg the tikz construction

```
\useasboundingbox (-0.5pt,-0.5pt) rectangle (5pt,8pt);
```

with appropriate choices of coordinates.  (This will avoid the `\vcenter` type juggling you have in your code.)

*Addition* If you are worried about the overhead of using a tikz command each time, which I don't think is high in this case, then you can instead of using newcommands use boxes as follows with `\newsavebox`, `\sbox` and `\usebox`:

```
\newsavebox{\mysetminusD}
\sbox{\mysetminusD}{\hbox{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.6pt,line cap=round]
(3pt,0) -- (0,6pt);}}}
\newsavebox{\mysetminusT}
\sbox{\mysetminusT}{\mysetminusD}
\newsavebox{\mysetminusS}
\sbox{\mysetminusS}{\hbox{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.45pt,line
cap=round] (2pt,0) -- (0,4pt);}}}
\newsavebox{\mysetminusSS}
\sbox{\mysetminusSS}{\hbox{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.4pt,line cap=round] (1.5pt,0) -- (0,3pt);}}}

\newcommand{\mysetminus}{\mathbin{\mathchoice{\usebox{\mysetminusD}}{\usebox{\mysetminusT}}{\usebox{\mysetminusS}}{\usebox{\mysetminusSS}}}}
```

Comment: I didn't know this: `line cap=round`. A new little question. With the other methods we are using *letters* or modified *letters*, but with this method we are using TikZ every time we write `\mysetminus`. I don't know if this is a real problem or not. But I would like to save the command into a *glyph* or *letter* (I don't know how to say that, like take a snapshot). If this is a silly thing just don't answer me. However, I like the answer.

Comment: @Manuel I have updated my answer to include a version that saves the glyphs in boxes.

Comment: Mmm, sorry, but it's not perfect. I imagined that those saveboxes should work as I have in mind (but they don't, apart that you didn't know what I had in mind because I didn't explained well). My idea, when I say *save to a glyph* is that it scales with the font: in this case, if you write `\Large` at the beginning of the document, the `\mysetminus` doesn't scale and look small. Is possible to make it scale good?

Comment: OK that is new information.  If you retain the unsaved tikz version, then you can use `em` as units instead of `pt`.  These following the scaling of the font.  For the savedbox version, you could use the `graphicx` package and a `scalebox` command, appropriately adapted.

Answer (score 13):

You could rotate `\smallsetminus`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand\rsetminus{\mathbin{\mathpalette\rsetminusaux\relax}}
\newcommand\rsetminusaux[2]{\mspace{-4mu}
  \raisebox{\rsmraise{#1}\depth}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-20}{$#1\smallsetminus$}}
 \mspace{-4mu}
}
\newcommand\rsmraise[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle .8\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle .8\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle .6\else
        .45%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}

\begin{document}
$A\rsetminus B_{A\rsetminus B_{A\rsetminus B}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. This is more a kind of personal choice, but again this doesn't satisfy me at all. I would like the backslash to be smaller (like the pictures I posted). And if I substitute the `\textstyle` by the `\scriptstyle` we are again in the same problem (it's thinner than it should).

Answer (score 8):

As you are not happy with the standard choices I suggest you try the `\fgebackslash` from the [fge package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fge).  Here it is in the middle between `\setminus` and `\smallsetminus`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,fge}
\newcommand{\mysetminus}{\mathbin{\fgebackslash}}

\begin{document} 

\( A\setminus B \qquad A \mysetminus B \qquad
A\smallsetminus B \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't like it. It's too thick and too tall. But at this moment, it's better than my solution because if you define `\newcommand{\mysetminus}{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\fgebackslash$}}}}` it is very similar and has the extra that it works in a subscript (with `\scriptscriptstyle`).

Comment: Thinking a little bit more, if we could scale only x axis of the symbol we could get a thinner and perfect one. I will look around.