# \caption versus a new setminus

Tags: captions

I'm using the following as [an improvement to the look of `\setminus`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87117):

```
\newcommand\rsetminus{\mathbin{\mathpalette\rsetminusaux\relax}}
\newcommand\rsetminusaux[2]{\mspace{-4mu}
\raisebox{\rsmraise{#1}\depth}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-20}{$#1\smallsetminus$}}
 \mspace{-4mu}
}
\newcommand\rsmraise[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle .8\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle .8\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle .6\else
        .45%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
```

`\rsetminus` works fine in math mode, but inside a figure caption in math mode it produces an error that the "argument of `\@caption` has an extra `}`".

I added \protect  before the \rotatebox.  No effect.  I have another command that uses `\raisebox` to move the Greek letter chi up to the normal line.  It has a `\protect` before the `\raisebox` and works fine inside a figure caption in math mode.

I also tried with `\ensuremath` before the `\protect`. Advice?

Comment: you'd need `\protect\rsetminus`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The simplest is to say `\protect\rsetminus` in the caption, if you need it only once. Or just change `\newcommand\rsetminus` into `\DeclareRobustCommand\rsetminus`.

Comment: as a matter of curiosity, why are you raising the `\smallsetminus`?  it's a binary operator, and as such, it is, by design, centered vertically on the math axis.  your raising it puts it almost at a superscript position.

Comment: Hello Barbara  --

Comment: Hello barbara. I copied a previous answer for improving the look of setminus.  It does not resemble longhand. It comes out OK in pdf with the raisebox.  But I'll try it plain too if this DeclareRobustCommand from egreg works.  (Just adding \protect did not work.)  I don't like they way  chi  and gamma are below the normal line, even though that's how real Greek is.  Math greek can be how we want it.  If you have  the characteristic function of a set  S  you want  chi sub S.  Without raising chi it looks wrong mathematically.  Thanks for your comment and inquiry.  Charles Pugh

Comment: Hi egreg.  \DeclareRobustCommand worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.  Charles Pugh

Answer (score 2):

An error such as

```
argument of \@caption has an extra }
```

usually means “you have a fragile command in the argument to `\caption`. As `\mathbin` is not fragile, the culprit must be `\mathpalette` or `\rsetminusaux` and indeed this one uses `\raisebox` which is fragile.

Solution:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\rsetminus{\mathbin{\mathpalette\rsetminusaux\relax}}
```

instead of `\newcommand`.